# Laravel перестали работать очереди

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, очередь

я разрабатываю игру про майнинг на laravel, в ней каждую минуту выполняется тяжелый алгоритм, который считает параметры комплектующих и ригов у игроков. Он выполняется в среднем 14 секунд для 1600 комплектующих)

Полгода всё работало исправно.
Но вчера ни с того, ни с сего вдруг скрипт просто перестал запускаться

P.s скрипт запускается каждую минуту через джоб, который прописан в larave schedule (на shared хостинге php artisan schedule:run выполняется также каждую минуту). Он состоит из 3 частей - получение данных из ДБ, их обработка и сохранение изменений в БД.

Помогает полный сброс кэша `php artisan optimaze:clear`. Но после этого скрипт выполняется всего один раз и перестает работать. На сервере ничего не меняли, я код не менял - всё чисто.

**Ошибки**

ОШИБОК НЕТ! Логи пустые, НО

Пару раз ловил ошибку Too many attempts or too long - MiningRunJob ... Но алгоритм всегда выполняется до 20 секунд уж точно, а ограничение в 60 секунд. Тем более я его даже явно прописывал, когда запускаю `queue:work --timeout=60`.

В job'e вначале и в конце есть вызов Log. Так вот, они оба всегда выводились в логи, но сейчас даже первый лог не выводится. Приэтом, если прописать логирование в `Kernel.php`, где прописываются расписания scheduler'a, то они исправно отрабатывают каждую минуту.
P.s. jobs и failed_jobs в бд чистил

Иногда почему-то выскакивает ошибка `could not find driver (SQL: select ... FROM ...)`. НО ПОЧЕМУ?? БД с сайтом нормально работает, даже после этого сбоя. До этого всё было ок, конфиги не менял.

Господи, что это может быть?

**Вынес запуск алгоритма из джоба**
Хз, как это может повлиять на работу сайта, если выполнять его не в джобе.

Что ж, оно на первый взгляд работает, алгоритм отрабатывает. НО: треть вызовов алгоритма тупо пропускается. Я хз, какого черта это происходит, догадок O. Конкретнее: в логах я вижу такую картину

```
start
end
start
start
start
end
start
start
```

И ошибок нет! На хостинге в тех.поддержке говорят, что с их стороны всё чисто, ограничений нет.

Я даже переписал немного код и разделил получение данных из БД на чанки по 200 запсей - не помогло

Вы - моя надежда

Comment: Я вынес логику из джоба просто в artisan комманду, но всё равно пропускается очень много вызовов алгаритма. В логи выводится start, но end нет, а потом на следующем вызове end появляется. Я не понмаю, почему это проиходит

Comment: добрый день, удалось ли вам решить проблему?

Comment: Да, удалось, но я уже забыл как(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что воркеры постоянно запускались, но никогда не завершались. Из-за этого и были лаги.
Переписал команду запуска воркера с параметром stop-when-enpty

`php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty`